# How to make a change to the source code in Haskell using GHCi?

Tags: macos, haskell, terminal, ghci

I am new to Haskell and am using GHCi to edit and run Haskell files. For some reason, I am not able to edit the source code of the file. The behavior I am getting is extremely odd.

Below is a screenshot of what is happening. I am loading the file lec3.hs and am attempting to edit this file to add the following function: `myfun = \w -> not w`. For some reason, this function successfully runs when I call it *immediately* after: `myfun False`. I do not need to reload the file.

It is clear that the function is not being added to the source code. When I reload the file, I am getting an error stating that `myfun` does not exist.

Could someone help me understand why GHCi is behaving this way, and how to fix such behaviour? I have already spent an hour trying to figure this out. I would sincerely appreciate any help.

[image: Image of GHCi prompts]

Comment: Defining stuff in GHCi isn't supposed to have the effect of adding that stuff to the code files. Never was. If you want to add your function to the code file, just open it in a text editor and edit.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Fyodor. Is it possible to edit a .hs file from GHCi?

Comment: Well, sure. You can write a little program in Haskell that would open the file, write the text into it, then close it. If you type that program into GHCi and run it, you will have edited the code file from GHCi. But that's definitely not what it was intended for.

Comment: Excellent, makes sense — thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing things into GHCi isn't supposed to add them to the source.  But if you have loaded a file into GHCi you can edit it using the `:e` command, and when you close the editor it will be automatically reloaded.

You can use `:e filename.hs` if you are dealing with more than one file and you need to specify.

Generally it's easier to work in a separate editor and just reload into GHCi with `:r`, but `:e` is occasionally useful.

Answer (score 1):

To answer

> Is it possible to edit a .hs file from GHCi?

It technically speaking is possible, since Haskell has like any other language file-IO operations. Concretely, [`appendFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:appendFile) allows you to add content to a file.

```
$ cat >> Foo.hs   # Creating a simple Haskell file
foo :: Int
foo = 3

$ ghci Foo.hs 
GHCi, version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghc/ghci.conf
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> foo
3
*Main> appendFile "Foo.hs" $ "myfun = \\w -> not w"
*Main> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> myfun False
True
```

But this really is not a good way to edit files. It makes much more sense to have two windows open, one with a text editor and one with the REPL, i.e. with GHCi. It can be either two completely separate OS windows, or two sub-windows of your IDE or whatever, but in either case GHCi will be used only for evaluation and one-line prototyping, not for actually adding/editing code. (The one-line prototypes can be copy&pasted into the editor, if it helps.)